# Eclipse - view packages as heirarchical, but not if only package contains more than one item

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to get Eclipse to show packages in the package explorer this way I've seen elsewhere, but its two options (flat/hierarchical) aren't getting me there.

Flat looks like this:

- com.mything.example
- com.mything.example.subpackage1
- com.mything.example.subpackage2
- com.mything.example.subpackage2.eggplant

Hierarchical looks like this:

- com

  - mything

    - example

      - subpackage1
      - subpackage2

        - eggplant

I want this:

- com.mything.example

  - subpackage1
  - subpackage2.eggplant

Any help?

Edit:

Moreover, sometimes it works inconsistently:
[image: two muppets]

Comment: This can happen if there are hidden files in the intermediate packages - change the view filter to show ".* resources" and see if anything shows up.

Comment: No dice... I changed the filters and double checked for any hidden files, but they're clean.